# I need to append a value in an array to another value in python

Tags: django, python-3.x

This is the current json response

```
[
   [
      {
         "TO":"nathanoluwaseyi@gmail.com",
         "FROM":"johndoe@gmail.com",
         "SUBJECT":"This is the subject 1",
         "MESSAGE":[
            "First Message"
         ],
         "NAME":"John Doe",
         "DATE":"2019-08-18 19:48:10"
      },
      {
         "TO":"nathanoluwaseyi@gmail.com",
         "FROM":"johndoe@gmail.com",
         "SUBJECT":"This is the subject 2",
         "MESSAGE":[
            "Second message"
         ],
         "NAME":"John Doe",
         "DATE":"2019-08-18 19:48:10"
      }
   ]
]
```

But i want a situation whereby more than one of the response have the same *FROM* then, the *MESSAGE* should be together in this format or something like this. How do i go about this? Everything i have tried didn't work
the date issue can be left for now. the most important is getting the messages into one.

```
[
   [
      {
         "TO":"nathanoluwaseyi@gmail.com",
         "FROM":"johndoe@gmail.com",
         "SUBJECT":"This is the subject 1",
         "MESSAGE":[
            "First Message", "Second Message"
         ],
         "NAME":"John Doe",
         "DATE":"2019-08-18 19:48:10"
      }
   ]
]
```

Comment: If it has the same FROM, is it guaranteed to have the same TO and NAME and DATE? if not, what to do?

Comment: yes it has the same *TO*. But i need to get the messages into one

Comment: is there an extra nest? with the outermost "[]"

Comment: i don't think its useful. i probably got that when i was trying different stuffs to get it to work

Comment: The means to append a value is *literally* called ``append``. What *exactly* is your problem in doing this? What *exactly* have you tried? Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example of your failing attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
s = '[...]' # Json string
loaded = json.loads(s) # [[{one json thing}], [{second json thing}]]
loaded = [t[0] for t in loaded] # [{json}, {json}] :)

dictionary = {}
for item in loaded:
    FROM = item["FROM"] # From
    MESSAGE = item["MESSAGE"][0] # Message
    DATE = item["DATE"] # Date
    if FROM not in dictionary: # If it hasn't been seen before
        dictionary[FROM] = item.copy() # To preserve TO, SUBJECT, ...
        del dictionary[FROM]["MESSAGE"] # No more >:)
        del dictionary[FROM]["DATE"] # No more >:)
        dictionary[FROM]["MESSAGE-DATE"] = [] # This will store the message-date pairs as a tuple
    dictionary[FROM]["MESSAGE-DATE"].append((MESSAGE, DATE)) # Here, the message and date are combined into a single item as a tuple

for key in dictionary:
    print (dictionary[key])
```

I've included comments that should explain. Try and see if it fits your purpose :)

(Btw I haven't dealt with json before, just know that it's basically a dictionary haha)

Comment: ok what of in a scenario where we have like four  FROM and  two of them are the same while the remaining 2 are different, how will i go about that?

Comment: @Eniayomi same thing? My code groups the json by their FROM, using the `dictionary`. Each different `FROM1` and `FROM2` gets it's own "message list", which stores all messages from that `FROMx`

Comment: What do you mean? So is it not providing what you're expecting? Can you give me the test case you're using? Thank you (And the output)

Comment: i got it, it was a mistake from me

Comment: thanks  really appreciate. now can we take it a step forward. as regards the date of each message

Comment: so you want to group it by FROM and DATE? Like it doesn't need to be `FROM1-DATE1` and `FROM2-DATE2` but also `FROM1-DATE2`?

Comment: no just the FROM. but i would like to display the date of each Message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210591/discussion-between-gareth-ma-and-eniayomi).

Comment: hello if you are still here, i have a question

Comment: discuss in chat

Comment: hello @Gareth Ma can i have a chat with you?

Comment: Oh sry didn’t see m. Post the question in the chat I’ll take a look around 6-7 hrs later

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dict with the unfied messages, checking if 'FROM' is already present. If yes, append the message, otherwise, just add it:

```
def unify_messages(messages):
    unified_msgs = {}
    for message in messages:
        if message['FROM'] in unified_msgs:
            unified_msgs[message['FROM']]['MESSAGE'].extend(message['MESSAGE'])
        else:
            unified_msgs[message['FROM']] = message

    return [v for v in unified_msgs.values()]

for message in messages:
    unified_messages = unify_messages(messages)
```

If you try with:

```
messages = [
   [
      {
         "TO":"nathanoluwaseyi@gmail.com",
         "FROM":"johndoe@gmail.com",
         "SUBJECT":"This is the subject 1",
         "MESSAGE":[
            "First Message"
         ],
         "NAME":"John Doe",
         "DATE":"2019-08-18 19:48:10"
      },
      {
         "TO":"nathanoluwaseyi@gmail.com",
         "FROM":"johndoe@gmail.com",
         "SUBJECT":"This is the subject 2",
         "MESSAGE":[
            "Second message"
         ],
         "NAME":"John Doe",
         "DATE":"2019-08-18 19:48:10"
      },
      {
         "TO":"nathanoluwaseyi@gmail.com",
         "FROM":"alice@gmail.com",
         "SUBJECT":"This is the subject 1",
         "MESSAGE":[
            "First Message from alice"
         ],
         "NAME":"John Doe",
         "DATE":"2019-08-18 19:48:10"
      },
      {
         "TO":"nathanoluwaseyi@gmail.com",
         "FROM":"sam@gmail.com",
         "SUBJECT":"This is the subject 1",
         "MESSAGE":[
            "First Message from sam"
         ],
         "NAME":"John Doe",
         "DATE":"2019-08-18 19:48:10"
      },
   ]
]
```

You`ll get:

```
[{'DATE': '2019-08-18 19:48:10',
  'FROM': 'johndoe@gmail.com',
  'MESSAGE': ['First Message', 'Second message'],
  'NAME': 'John Doe',
  'SUBJECT': 'This is the subject 1',
  'TO': 'nathanoluwaseyi@gmail.com'},
 {'DATE': '2019-08-18 19:48:10',
  'FROM': 'alice@gmail.com',
  'MESSAGE': ['First Message from alice'],
  'NAME': 'John Doe',
  'SUBJECT': 'This is the subject 1',
  'TO': 'nathanoluwaseyi@gmail.com'},
 {'DATE': '2019-08-18 19:48:10',
  'FROM': 'sam@gmail.com',
  'MESSAGE': ['First Message from sam'],
  'NAME': 'John Doe',
  'SUBJECT': 'This is the subject 1',
  'TO': 'nathanoluwaseyi@gmail.com'}]
```

Comment: ok what of in a scenario where we have like four FROM and two of them are the same while the remaining 2 are different, how will i go about that?

Comment: This code doesn't do what he's trying to achieve, which is to group by the `FROM`, not just combining the MESSAGE

Comment: Changed the example, to group it by `FROM`

Comment: thanks  really appreciate. now can we take it a step forward. as regards the date of each message